# JDBC Driver for MSSQL with Java 10

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, ehcache

I use the old jtds driver. But it breaks the cache implementor for Hibernate 5/Ehcache 3. I tried the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver, but it only supports Java 9, not 10:

```
Exception in thread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge14g9v13ogz626urcor|6d77c929]-HelperThread-#1" ja
va.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent ve
rsion of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file version
s up to 52.0 (unable to load class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver])
```

I am flexible with Java 8, 9 or 10, I just need a JDBC driver that does not break Ehcache. For example, jdk 8 with jtds will cause "Cache failed to start" error  in ehcache/Spring.

Comment: The error actually means the driver was compiled with Java 9 (class version 53) and you are trying to run on Java 8 (max class version 52). Make sure you are executing your application with Java 9 or Java 10.

Comment: Looks like that one is fixed, thanks!   Jdk 10, hibernate 5.3 Spring 5, Ehcache 3.5, hibernate-jhcache 5.3, mssql-jdbc 6.4.0.jre9